# How can we reconcile Leviticus 11:7 & Deutoronomy 12:14-15?

Tags: contradiction, deuteronomy, leviticus

(KJV) Leviticus 11:7

> 7 And the swine, though he divide the hoof, and be clovenfooted, yet he cheweth not the cud;  he is unclean to you.   8 Of their flesh shall ***ye not eat***, and their carcase shall ye not touch;  they are unclean to you.

In Leviticus 11

clean animals allowed to be eaten

Unclean animals not to be eaten

(KJV) Deutoronomy 12:14

> 14 But in the place which the LORD shall choose in one of thy tribes, there thou shalt offer thy burnt offerings, and there thou shalt do all that I command thee.   15 Notwithstanding thou mayest kill and eat flesh in all thy gates, whatsoever thy soul lusteth after, according to the blessing of the LORD thy God which he hath given thee:  ***the unclean and the clean may eat*** thereof, as of the roebuck, and as of the hart.

But in Deutoronomy it seems both the unclean & clean is allowed to be consumed.

How can we understand the above texts?

Comment: This is an OT 101 type of question that does not show careful reading. Please review background material such as https://bible.org/seriespage/8-clean-and-unclean-part-i-leviticus-11

Comment: It is a point that needs to be borne in mind and can seem, at first, confusing: that some animals are clean and unclean: and that the eater _also_ may be clean or unclean. My thoughts are with you in the troublesome times that you are now experiencing in Zimbabwe.

Comment: Sometimes 'conventonal wisdom' doesn't satisfy.  One God loves the smell of burning flesh - the other God hates it.  One Ark distinguishes between clean (by 7's) and unclean (by 2's) - the other Ark takes all 2 by 2.  The OP's verses, to me, show this difference between which God was operating at the time.  Biblical astronomy may not  intrigue everyone, but it does me. I don't see contradictions, just a need to look for alternative explanations.

Comment: Eating an being eaten are two different things, wouldn't you agree ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leviticus 11:7 refers to "unclean" **animals**, not to be eaten by any Israelite at any time.

Deuteronomy 12:14 refers to **Israelites** in an "unclean" state, who are prohibited from eating animals sacrificed in the tabernacle, or temple (or on the private alters during the times that they we permitted) until "cleansed". These unclean people may nevertheless eat the meat of clean animals slaughtered for meat rather than as sacrifices.

Specific animals, carcasses and places such as grave sites are inherently "unclean" and cannot be cleansed. Israelites can become "unclean" to various degrees by contact with "unclean" things such as unclean animals, corpses, graves, menstruating women, seminal fluid, biblical "leprosy" and others. Depending on the degree of "uncleanness" they can be cleansed by rituals ranging from waiting until sundown and changing clothes to requiring to be sprinkled with water containing ashes of a burnt red heifer twice during a period of a week.